# How to provide custom formatting from format string?

Tags: python, string, format

I can use a custom class to extend Python's string formatting:

```
class CaseStr(str):
    def __format__(self, fmt):
        if fmt.endswith('u'):
            s = self.upper()
            fmt = fmt[:-1]
        elif fmt.endswith('l'):
            s = self.lower()
            fmt = fmt[:-1]
        else:
            s = str(self)
        return s.__format__(fmt)
```

I can then use this class to format arguments which are passed to a strings format method:

```
unformatted_string = 'uppercase: {s:u}, lowercase: {s:l}'
print unformatted_string.format(s=CaseStr('abc'))
```

While this works it seems awkward that the custom format specifier is in the base string, but the arguments passed to it's format method are actually responsible for parsing the format specifier.

Is there a way to place the knowledge required to interpret the custom string within the base string itself?

```
class CaseStrWrapper(str):
    ...

unformatted_string = CaseStrWrapper('uppercase: {s:u}, lowercase: {s:l}')
print unformatted_string.format(s='abc')
```

Comment: You could overload format, but format specifier understanding is the job of the thing to be formatted, not `str`'s job. This is much like how each type has its own `__str__` method instead of trying to have the `str` class know how to stringify every type of object.

Comment: why not just use format strings? e.g. `f"{s.upper()} {s.lower()}"`?

Comment: It sounds like a formatting tool other than `str.format` would be more appropriate for what you want to do.

Comment: @SamMason I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would normally use [custom string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) for that (see [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)). For your case, you could have something like this:

```py
import string

class MyFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            if format_spec.endswith('u'):
                value = value.upper()
                format_spec = format_spec[:-1]
            elif format_spec.endswith('l'):
                value = value.lower()
                format_spec = format_spec[:-1]
        return super(MyFormatter, self).format(value, format_spec)

fmt = MyFormatter()
print(fmt.format('uppercase: {s:u}, lowercase: {s:l}', s='abc'))
# uppercase: ABC, lowercase: abc
```